# Read frame by frame and create video using cv2 in python

Tags: python, video, opencv

I want to read frame by frame from existing video, and create new video from these frames.

In my real project I want to change each frame before making the new video but for simplicity's sake of this question I just want to create new video from the same frames without any change.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('input_video.mp4')
vidwrite = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), 30, (1920,1080))
success,image = vidcap.read()
while success:
  vidwrite.write(image) # write frame into video
  success,image = vidcap.read() # read frame from video
vidwrite.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The strange thing is that the output video is twice bigger than the input video

Comment: "The strange thing" -- not really. It just means that the default configuration used by this particular codec in OpenCV is different to what the author of the source video used to encode it. This is nothing unusual when dealing with data compression.